# ffmpeg live webcam colorkey subtraction and dispaly feed on desktop (with subtracted color transparent/desktop see through visible))

Tags: ffmpeg, mplayer, webcam-capture, color-key

**Purpose:** I want to create instructional video lectures using laptop webcam and presentation slides. Here I should be visible in bottom right corner of desktop in small screen or full screen explaining slides. (like TV weather report).

**What I seek:** Is there any way to apply colorkey to live webcam video to subtract background (greenscreen) so that desktop is visible through the top webcam borderless video window.(Then record everything on desktop)

**What I have done:** I have been successful in overlaying colorkeyed live webcam video and X11grab :0.0 and saving the output in a video file.

```
    ffmpeg -f x11grab -thread_queue_size 64 -video_size 1024X600 -framerate 30 -i :0.0 -f  v4l2 -thread_queue_size 64 -video_size 320X180 -framerate 30 -i /dev/video0 -filter_complex '[1:v]colorkey=0x000000:0.1:0[ckout];[0:v][ckout] overlay=main_w-overlay_w:main_h-overlay_h:format=yuv444' -vcodec libx264 -preset ultrafast -qp 0 -pix_fmt yuv444p video.mp4
```

But this is not I want. Because this way I cannot see what actually is happening on desktop and where should I point on the slide (lack of instructional control).

I also successfully piped this composite output through ffplay [ - | ffplay  -i -] but it creates a mirror in mirror effect so thus useless.

What I expect: I just want to apply ffmpge colorkey  to the webcam feed /dev/video0 and display color subtracted output on desktop so that the subtracted region in the video player (ffplay/mplayer) should appear transparent and desktop should be visible (video player should preserve alpha channel and appear transparent in colorkeyed region). (weatherman effect).

**Roughly I am looking for**
ffmpeg {-i /dev/video0} {colorkry[ckout]} {-| ffplay -i - } or { - | mplayer} -

**Note:** I know openbroadcaster can do this job, I tried to install it but it does not execute citing "Failed to initialize video.  Your GPU may not be supported, or your graphics drivers may need to be updated." I have a old laptop 2GB RAM and Atom processor running Xubuntu 16.04. probably openbroadcaster cant support.

As I have successfully oberlayed colorkeyed webcam feed with X11grab (with maximum 50% cpu usage) I think it is easily possible to do live webcam colerkey subtraction with available resources.

Please give suggestions.

Comment: Don't believe this possible. ffplay will composite video over black canvas, not over desktop.

Comment: True that seems the case. But could there be any alternative? Not exactly the way I described above

Comment: To prevent mirror effect I tried to pipe composite of :0.0 & webcam color keyed feed through additional xsession at tty1. but the composite shows black screen for :0.0, shows cursor and nice webcam feed. I dont know why screen captures black. If this can be solved I think it can be a solution.